# Substitute compound expression in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

In sympy how can I make a substitution of a compound expression for a single variable as in the following example that only works for one of the instances of the common factor?

```py
from sympy import *
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')

eq = Eq(2*(x+y) + 3*(x+y)**2, 0)
print(eq)
eq1 = Eq(z, x+y)
print(eq1)
eq2 = eq.subs(eq1.rhs, eq1.lhs)
print(eq2)
```

Output

```
Eq(2*x + 2*y + 3*(x + y)**2, 0)
Eq(z, x + y)
Eq(2*x + 2*y + 3*z**2, 0)
```

Desired output for last line

```
Eq(2*z + 3*z**2, 0)
```

Comment: Substituting for compound expressions is fragile, ambiguous and not well defined in general. I suggest doing `eq2.subs(x, z-y)` which is well defined. If that does not work for your general problem then you'll need to clarify more precisely what the general case is that you want to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substitution fails because subs does not encounter any argument `x + y` in the (sub)expression `2*(x + y)`: that expression automatically expands to `2*x + 2*y`. So one solution is to do as Oscar suggested: make an algebraic substitution. I often follow this up with a restoration step to handle anything that didn't change as I expected. The other thing you can do is to use a helper function that groups together terms that are in the multi-term `old` object that you desire to replace:

```py
def mvsubs(eq, old, new):
    from sympy.core.exprtools import factor_terms
    if not old.is_Add:
        return eq.subs(old, new)
    Add = old.func
    free = old.free_symbols
    for i in eq.atoms(Add):
        reps = {}
        for i in i.args:
            if not all(i.has(x) for x in free):
                reps.setdefault(i, Dummy())
        eq = eq.subs(reps).subs(Add(*reps.values()),
                                factor_terms(Add(*reps.keys()))).subs(
            old, new).xreplace({v:k for k,v in reps.items()})
    return eq

>>> mvsubs(eq, x+y, z)
Eq(3*z**2 + 2*z, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Oscar Benjamin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9450991/oscar-benjamin) comment. I've solved the case I was actually interested in:

```py
from sympy import *
t, L, C0, R, a, w0, h = symbols('t L C_0 R alpha omega_0 h')
Q = Function('Q')
ex0 = L*Q(t).diff(t, t) + R*Q(t).diff(t) + Q(t)*(1/(C0/(1+h*cos(a*t))))
print(ex0)
ex1 = ex0/L
ex1 = ex1.collect(Q(t)).expand()
print(ex1)
# substitute the following compound expression
ex2 = Eq(w0*w0, 1/(L*C0))
print(ex2)
ex3 = ex1.subs(L*C0, 1/(w0*w0))
ex4 = ex3.collect(Q(t))
print(ex4)
```

Output:

```py
L*Derivative(Q(t), (t, 2)) + R*Derivative(Q(t), t) + (h*cos(alpha*t) + 1)*Q(t)/C_0
Derivative(Q(t), (t, 2)) + R*Derivative(Q(t), t)/L + h*Q(t)*cos(alpha*t)/(C_0*L) + Q(t)/(C_0*L)
Eq(omega_0**2, 1/(C_0*L))
(h*omega_0**2*cos(alpha*t) + omega_0**2)*Q(t) + Derivative(Q(t), (t, 2)) + R*Derivative(Q(t), t)/L
```